# I removed branch with unstaged changes - can I revert this?

Tags: git, version-control

I've accidentally removed branch with unstaged/uncommitted changes there - I've tried to go back using `git reflog` and then `git checkout` commands but it goes back to branch state without my changes that hasn't been commited. Is there anything to revert this operation and retrieve my unstaged changes on that (deleted) branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes won't be in any branch if they were unstaged. If you have not overwritten the changes in what you have done since, you might be able to commit these changes to your current branch or a new branch. But if those changes have already disappeared and you did not [`stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) them. They are now gone.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.. They're gone :/ Thank You anyway for the confirmation of my worst scenario :/

Comment: It doesn't help you now, I know, but it's always good to get in the habit of frequent commits.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I was actually cleaning out my branches (I've done various things, merged one with another with file deletion etc. and wanted to clean it before commit - but that was an awful mistake - next time I'll commit everything and then do the cleaning T_T ).